# strfmt range in x++

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-365

what's wrong with this range?

```
rangeTransDate = strFmt('(("%1.%2" <= "%3" && "%3" == "%5") || ("%1.%4" > "%3"))',tableStr(CustomTable),fieldStr(CustomTable,TransDate), date2str(dateTo,321,2,0,2,0,4),fieldStr(CustomTable,SettlementDate),SysQuery::valueEmptyString());
```

i'm getting this error:

> Query extended range error: Right parenthesis expected next to position 72.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page of [AX 2012 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/using-expressions-in-query-ranges) is still relevant (I cannot find a AX365 version). Highlighting the important bit gives:

> The rules for creating query range value expressions are:
>
> - Enclose the whole expression in parentheses.
> - **Enclose all subexpressions in parentheses.**
> - Use the relational and logical operators available in X++.
> - Only use field names from the range's data source.
> - Use the dataSource.field notation for fields from other data sources in the query.

This means that X++ expects curly brackets around *every* comparison operator (a.k.a. "subexpression" in the documentation). You are missing some...

Also, use the `date2strxpp()` function to properly handle all date to string conversions. This function can handle empty date values (`dateNull()`) by translating these to `1900-01-01`. I doubt that putting an empty string (`SysQuery::valueEmptyString()`) in there will work.

So try this, the commented subexpression levels show the bracket groupings:

```
// subexpressions lvl 2: 4                                                       4
// subexpressions lvl 1: |1               1    2            2    3              3|
//                       ||               |    |            |    |              ||
rangeTransDate = strFmt('(("%1.%2" <= "%3") && ("%3" == "%5") || ("%1.%4" > "%3"))',
                        tableStr(CustomTable),
                        fieldStr(CustomTable,TransDate),
                        date2strxpp(dateTo),
                        fieldStr(CustomTable,SettlementDate),
                        date2strxpp(dateNull()));
```

If you *still* get a similar error at runtime, add even more brackets to group every subexpression in pairs:

```
// subexpressions lvl 3: 5                                                         5
// subexpressions lvl 2: |4                                   4    3              3|
// subexpressions lvl 1: ||1               1    2            2|    3              3|
//                       |||               |    |            ||    |              ||
rangeTransDate = strFmt('((("%1.%2" <= "%3") && ("%3" == "%5")) || ("%1.%4" > "%3"))',
                        tableStr(CustomTable),
                        fieldStr(CustomTable,TransDate),
                        date2strxpp(dateTo),
                        fieldStr(CustomTable,SettlementDate),
                        date2strxpp(dateNull()));
```